# Big O complexity of $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\log(n)$

Tags: asymptotics, computational-complexity

I am trying to evaluate the Big $O$ complexity of $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\log(n)$. I've tried approaching it using Telescopic sum, and arrived at the following:
$$T(n)=2^{k}T\left(\frac{n}{2^{k}}\right)+\sum_{i=1}^{k}2^{i-1}\log\left(\frac{n}{2^{i-1}}\right)$$
To solve this equation we can put $k=\log(n)$ and compute the order of the sum, which is equal to the following condensed product:
$$\log\left(n\left(\frac{n}{2}\right)^{2}\left(\frac{n}{4}\right)^{4}\cdots\left(\frac{n}{2^{k-1}}\right)^{2^{k-1}}\right)$$
I am not able to proceed. Any hints would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: AFAICT, best way to solve this is to introduce $U(k):=T(2^k)/2^k$. Then $U$ satisfies $$U(k+1)-U(k)=\frac{k+1}{2^{k+1}}$$
(since this looks like the complexity of a divide-and-conquer algorithm I assume a base-$2$ logarithm), and there is your telescopic sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\log\left[\prod_{j=0}^{k-1}\left(\frac{n}{2^j}\right)^{2^j}\right]=
\log\left[n^{\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}2^j}\cdot2^{-\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}j2^{j}}\right]=$$
There is an exercise for you to prove the following identity:
$$\sum_{j=1}^{k}j2^j = 2^{k+1}(k-1)+2$$
Now we continue:
$$=\log\left[n^{2^k-1}\cdot2^{-(2^k(k-2)+2)}\right]=(2^k-1)\log n - (2^k(k-2)+2)=$$
$$=2^k\log n-\log n - 2^k k+2^{k+1}-2= \{k=\log n\}=O(n) $$

Comment: Thanks, that clarifies it.